# Computational complexity of the Cholesky factorization

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, symmetry, cholesky-decomposition

According to the Cholesky factorization on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), the computational complexity of it is $\frac{n^3}{3}$ FLOPs where $n$ is the size of the considered matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

> There are various methods for calculating the Cholesky decomposition. The computational complexity of commonly used algorithms is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ in general.The algorithms described below all involve about $n^3/3$ FLOPs ($n^3/6$ multiplications and the same number of additions), where $n$ is the size of the matrix A. Hence, they have half the cost of the LU decomposition, which uses $2n^3/3$ FLOPs (see Trefethen and Bau 1997).

To more understand how this number comes out, I was using a $3\times3$ real symmetric matrix, which can be found from [this lecture note, pp.12.17--12.18](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/133A/lectures/chol.pdf).

For convenience, let me assume the computational complexity (or the floating point operation, FLOP) for `multiplication`, `addition/subtraction`, `division`, and `square-root` is $1$.

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is defined as

$$
\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 25 & 15 & -5\\15 & 18 & 0\\-5 & 0 & 11\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} R_{11} & 0 & 0\\R_{12} & R_{22} & 0\\R_{13} & R_{23} & R_{33} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13}\\ 0 & R_{22} & R_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & R_{33} \end{bmatrix}\ .
$$

We need to compute the following to find $R_{11}$:

$$R_{11}^2 = 25 \rightarrow R_{11} = 5,$$

and the plus 5 is chosen for convenience.

From the equation above, we easily can see that one `squareroot` is required to compute $R_{11}$.

For $R_{12}$ and $R_{13}$, we might compute the following:

$$ R_{12} = 15R_{11}^{-1} = 3, $$

$$ R_{13} = -5R_{11}^{-1} = -1, $$

which requires one `division`, respectively.

In total, so far, a total of $3$ FLOPs is required for $R_{11}$, $R_{12}$, and $R_{13}$.

Let me write the rest elements below.

$$R_{22} = \sqrt{18-R_{12}^2} = 3,$$

$$R_{23} = \frac{0-R_{13}R_{12}}{R_{22}} = 1,$$

$$R_{33} = \sqrt{11 - R_{13}^2 - R_{23}^2} = 3,$$

Therefore, it is a total of 14 FLOPS for the Cholesky factorization, which can be found in the following table:

| Element | $\times$ | $+, -$ | $\div$ | $\sqrt{\cdot}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $R_{11}$ | $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $1$ |
| $R_{12}$ | $0$ | $0$ | $1$ | $0$ |
| $R_{13}$ | $0$ | $0$ | $1$ | $0$ |
| $R_{22}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $0$ | $1$ |
| $R_{23}$ | $1$ | $1$ | $1$ | $0$ |
| $R_{33}$ | $2$ | $2$ | $0$ | $1$ |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Total | $4$ | $4$ | $3$ | $3$ |

It should have been $9$ FLOPs according to $n^3/3$, but the FLOPs that were obtained were $14$.

Is there any miscomputation? Or there should be something that I am missing or misunderstanding?